# Why this code is not showing CircularProgressIndicator?

Tags: flutter

This is a simple code which display a different Text based in a random number. I want to show the CircularProgressIndicator when the user push 'next' button and the method 'getRandom' delays 5 secs.

CircularProgressIndicator never is shown...why?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}


class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<String> random;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    random = getRandom();
  }

  Future<String> getRandom() async{
    print("getRandom");
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    return "the number is"+Random().nextInt(100).toString();
  }


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Random Widget")),
          body: Center(child:
          FutureBuilder(
              future:random,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Column(children: [
                    Text(snapshot.data,textScaleFactor: 4),
                    getNextButton()
                  ]);
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text("ERROR");
                }
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
          )
      )),
    );
  }

  Widget getNextButton(){
      return RaisedButton(
          child: Text("NEXT"),
          color: Colors.red,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              random=getRandom();
            });
          }
      );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code.

1. You are passing `initialData`. So the snapshot.hasData will be true in the beginning itself.
2. You didn't initialise the random for the first time.
3. You have to await your Future.delay

Change getRandom implementation:

```
Future<String> getRandom() async{
   await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
   return "the number is"+ Random().nextInt(100).toString();
}
```

Implement initState to initialise random future:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  random = getRandom();
}
```

Change future builder:

```
FutureBuilder(
   future:random,
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
         return Column(children: [
            Text(snapshot.data,textScaleFactor: 4),
            getNextButton()
          ]);
       } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("ERROR");
       }
       return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
)
```

Comment: I changed the initial code including your suggestions. Not luck :( Progress not appears.

Comment: I tried. Delays 10 secs to show the next Text. Progress is not showing :(

Comment: Yes, It works!!! I dont know why the conditional is important

snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done


I will check the doc again. Thanks!!!!

Comment: i tried it. it work. but, data can't finish loading

Comment: @MichaelFernando Could you please explain the issue you are facing?

Comment: oh, nope. i have resolved my case with this solution. i was forgot about my structure code @MidhunMP

Answer (score 0):

If your not using your `initialData` field in you FutureBuilder than delete and your code will work. If you for some reason need that value add the following statement to the end:

```
if(snapshot.data != 'starting') {
  return CircularProgressIndicator();
}
```

See the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html#widgets.FutureBuilder.1) for an example of how to use it

Comment: It was a mistake. I replaced the line returning a Text by a new one returning a CircularProgressIndicator.

It did not work :(

Comment: I think that because you set the initialData to 'starting', you will either have to remove that line if there is no good reason for it or make the if statement look like: `snapshot.data != 'starting'. This should fix it.

Comment: Thank you Gabe. I removed the initialData line and the good new is that CircularProgressIndicator is displayed!!! The bad one is that never dissapears!!! :)

Comment: Does your Column appear? Make sure you return CircularProgressIndicator in the else block.

Comment: Yes, I tried.inside the else block. Column not appears, only the CircularProgressIndicator only.